# Singleton, cannot go in the runnable task

Tags: java-8, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice, vaadin8

I'm trying to run a task automatically (all the 30s).

For that, I built a singleton :

```
public class PortalSingleton {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PortalSingleton.class);
    private static final int INITIAL_DELAY = 0;
    private static final int DELAY = 30;

    private static volatile ScheduledExecutorService instance;
    private static HomepageView homeView = new HomepageView();

    private PortalSingleton() {}

    public static final void refreshGridHomePageAutomatically() {
        Runnable task = () -> UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
            homeView.refreshGrid();
            LOG.info("The grid has been refreshed Automatically");
        });
        getInstance().scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, INITIAL_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public final static ScheduledExecutorService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (ScheduledExecutorService.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But, I didn't have any issue/error AND I didn't have my log msg and my grid hasn't been refreshed..

The behavior expected is :

1. my grid refresh
2. see the log msg

Even if I delete the line `homeView.refreshGrid();`, I don't have my log msg...

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,

EDIT : I call it by doing : `PortalSingleton.refreshGridHomePageAutomatically();`

EDIT2, thanks @Holger :

```
public class PortalSingleton {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PortalSingleton.class);
    private static final int INITIAL_DELAY = 0;
    private static final int DELAY = 30;

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService instance = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private static HomepageView homeView = new HomepageView();

    private PortalSingleton() {
    }

    public static final void refreshGridHomePageAutomatically() {
        Runnable task = () -> UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
            homeView.refreshGrid();
            LOG.info("The grid has been refreshed Automatically");
        });
        try {
            getInstance().scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, INITIAL_DELAY, DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("error" + e);
        }
    }

    public final static ScheduledExecutorService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: not complaining.. I'm expecting to see msg "The grid has been refreshed Automatically" and my grid refreshed but I don't have the expecting behavior. So I don't understand what did I do wrong, because, I don't have any error msg...

Comment: @Holger, I edited my post, Is it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use try/catch (see the EDIT2 in my post) for the ScheduledExecutorService. I assumed this is not good because I don't have any error and still don't have the expected behavior.

Comment: You're right !! NPE! Thanks for your help!!! Would you like to put it as answer?I'll be able to close this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you schedule an action, you do not get a feedback when an exception occurs. Instead, it will just stop executing it:

[`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> …If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.

Therefore, you will have to use a `try … catch` block in the action itself to report it, e.g. in the lambda expression defining your `Runnable`:

```
Runnable task = () -> {
    try { UI.getCurrent().access(…); }
    catch (Exception e) { LOG.error("error" + e); }
};
```

It looks suspicious to me that you are calling `UI.getCurrent()` from a non-UI thread which I suspect to return `null` causing a `NullPointerException` when trying to invoke a method on it.

Comment: Yes, You're totally right: I should not call the UI.getCurrent(), I deleted it. I'm not in a UI. When I debug, I haven't an NPE on UI.getCurrent(), but the NPE appear with the Try/Catch Thanks again for your help !